# Task Core dividing

Tags: c++, directx, windows

How can I divide the tasks for diffrent cores?

E.g. 4 Cores
func1() -> core1

func2() -> core2

func3() -> core3

func4() -> core4

Is there special libary for this? Or do I have to use the old fashioned way of integrating 
the functions in the main loop ?

( I'm using C++ on Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if there might be ways to select specific cores for parallel tasks, it's considered bad practice. Number of cores vary from machine to machine, and it's better to let the OS decide where to put the load. You should just [create a few Windows threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and let the scheduler manage.